# org-projectile agenda view?

Tags: org-agenda, projectile

I'm trying to create a custom agenda to show todos for the current project logged via `org-projectile`. Something like this:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
            '(("p" "Current project"
         ((tags (concat "CATEGORY=\"" (projectile-project-name) "\""))))))
```

However, since this is called from the agenda dispatcher, `projectile-project-name` is `-`.

How can I create an agenda view for the current `projectile` project?

---

Additional details:

I have one `projects.org` file already added to `org-agenda-files` with headlines formatted like so:

```
* my-project
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CATEGORY: my-project
  :END:
** TODO some project-specific todo
```

Comment: I presume your `project.org` file(s) are all on `org-agenda-files`, so when you ask for the agenda, you get TODO items for *every* project? And you are interested in limiting that just to one project (the one returned by `projectile-project-name` at the current time) - is that correct?

Comment: @NickD yes, that's exactly correct! I realize that keeping track of the project once I open the dispatcher might be tricky, so I'd also happily accept a function that I could bind to a key directly that would bring up the view.

Comment: I think a function to bring up the view is the way to go: it can determine the current project easily at the time of the call and that's a necessary prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `project.org` file at the root of each project that contains the TODO items for that project, here's a simple function to do what I think you want:

```el
(defun ndk/agenda-for-project ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((project-name (projectile-project-name))
         (project-root (projectile-project-root))
         (org-agenda-files (list (concat project-root "project.org")))
         (org-agenda-custom-commands `(("p" ,project-name tags-todo))))
    (org-agenda-list "p")))
```

It basically let-binds `org-agenda-files` to a list of the single `project.org` file in the project's root and `org-agenda-custom-comands` to something that will show the TODO items; and then calls `org-agenda-list` with the `p` setting defined in the let-bound value of `org-agenda-custom-commands`. You can bind the function to a key of your choice e.g.

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") #'ndk/agenda-for-project)
```

The custom agenda command is just an example for testing: you can make it as complicated as you want. I use the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) mechanism to pass calculated values into a basically constant list as an illustration of how to do similar things in more complicated situations: it does not buy us much with the simple custom command I used.

The restriction that the Org mode file is called `project.org` in every project can be relaxed a bit, but there needs to be some convention, so that the function could calculate it easily. But making it a constant is simple and not particularly restrictive IMO.

Lightly tested. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! This isn't quite working for me; I added details to the question for how my file is organized.

Comment: So one file for all the projects: the projects are top-level headlines with the details of each project as second-level (or deeper) headlines, correct?

Comment: I have tried changing the structure to what (I think) you use, but I have not been able to come up with a custom agenda that works with it (and I don't understand why what I have tried is not working). I'll keep plugging at it for a while longer and hope for success at some point - but not yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

author of org-projectile here. I think the right approach to this is to use category narrowing. org-projectile is built to work with categories.